Caddy response not working when in a Container with port forwarding (error:0A000438:SSL)
I'm using Docker to run Caddy.
My host IP Address is 10.0.0.5 and my Caddyfile looks like this:
10.0.0.5:443 {
        log
        respond "Hello world"
}

When running Caddy in the host network with
docker container run -it --rm --network=host -v ./mycaddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile caddy

This works like a charm and I can curl it:
> curl -k https://10.0.0.5
Hello world

BUT
when I change from host network to port forwarding, this doesn't work any more:
docker container run -it --rm -p 443:443 -v ./mycaddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile caddy

> curl -k https://10.0.0.5
curl: (35) error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error

Help is appreciated
